# Having trouble aligning 3 textviews next to eachother in recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I am trying to align 3 text views but the textview contents are not  aligning with each other, since I plan to add 3 more and I want text values to line up.
The values line up if I align the first one to the parent left, second in the middle and the last one to the right, but I need space for 3 more text views.

Here is how it looks:

[RecyclerView Textviews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu4Zx.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Value"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Amount"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/value"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bids"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/amount"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give each textview the same width, you can ensure that they will line up with each other. You can achieve this by giving each textview a weight of 1 within a LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Value"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:gravity="left" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Amount"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:gravity="left" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bid"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Bids"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:gravity="left" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i think you are missing android:weightSum  on your ViewGroup i.e. LinearLayout

Comment: @FaisalNaseer Setting 'android:weightSum' is not required. What value would you set it to? According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum), "If unspecified, the sum is computed by adding the layout_weight of all of the children."